# Getting Total Sum Of All Values But Why It's Showing Same Total In All Dynamic Items

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.7

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*` ...

I have 12 input fields of `Taxes_Break_Up`, i need to sum all of them and show in `Total_Tax_BreakUp` field. I have `TicketInvoice` and a `TicketInvoice` has many `TicketInvoiceItems`, in my `TicketInvoiceItems` i have `Taxes_Breakup` fields and a `Total_Taxes_Breakup` field, i put values in `Taxes_Breakup` and get the sum in `Total_Taxes_Breakup`, but when i add `TicketInvoiceItems` fields dynamically, all the `Total_Tax_BreakUp` in `TicketInvoiceItems` is as same as the the first `TicketInvoiceItems`'s `Total_Tax_BreakUp` field... This might be confusing so i add an image for better understanding. Thank You.

Here is my `HTML` code:

```html
<tr v-for="(ticketInvoiceItem, pos) in form.ticketInvoiceItems" :key="pos">
  <!--Passenger Name-->
  <td>
    <input v-model="form.ticketInvoiceItems[pos].passenger_name" size="40" type="text" name="passenger_name" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('passenger_name') }">
    <has-error :form="form" field="passenger_name"></has-error>
  </td>

  <!-------------------Taxes BreakUps------------------->
  <input v-model="form.ticketInvoiceItems[pos].tax_SB" id="tax_SB" type="number" name="tax_SB" placeholder="SB" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('tax_SB') }">

  <input v-model="form.ticketInvoiceItems[pos].tax_SRP" id="tax_SRP" type="number" name="tax_SRP" placeholder="SRP" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('tax_SRP') }">
  <!-------------------AND 10 OTHER------------------->


  <!-------------------Total Taxes Break Up------------------->
  <td>
    <input :value="totalTax" id="total_tax_breakup" type="number" size="10" name="total_tax_breakup" class="table-control form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('total_tax_breakup') }">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my `VueJs` Code:

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        ticketInvoices: {},
        form: new Form({
          id: "",
          vendor_id: "",
          ticket_invoice_no: "",
          ticket_invoice_date: "",
          ticket_invoice_fares_total: "",
          ticket_invoice_taxes_grand_total: "",
          ticket_invoice_grand_total: "",

          ticketInvoiceItems: [{
            id: "",
            ticket_invoice_id: "",
            passenger_name: "",
            tax_SB: 0,
            tax_SRP: 0,
            tax_YQ: 0,
            tax_RG: 0,
            tax_PK: 0,
            tax_YR: 0,
            tax_SF: 0,
            tax_PTT: 0,
            tax_OAS: 0,
            tax_PSF: 0,
            tax_PB: 0,
            tax_OAD: 0,
            fares: "",
            total_tax_breakup: 0,
            sub_total: ""
          }]
        })
      };
    },
    computed: {
      totalTax() {
        let calTaxTotal =
          parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_SB) +
          parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_SRP) +
          parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_YQ) +
          parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_RG) +
          parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_PK) +
          parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_YR) +
          parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_SF) +
          parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_PTT) +
          parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_OAS) +
          parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_PSF) +
          parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_PB) +
          parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_OAD);

        this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].total_tax_breakup = calTaxTotal;

        return calTaxTotal;

      }
    },
  } 
  </script>
```

Getting This Error, when i sum all Taxes_Breakup,and when i add dynamic fields, all Total_taxes_breakup are copying the first one.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue Thank You so much for ur support,

The problem is in my computed property. All of my `indexes` are at `[0]`, or the first row of my table. If i want to add up more than one row i need to pass the [index] into my `totalTax`. So a computed property is not the best choice. So i turn it into a method instead and pass the `index (or key)` into the method.

```html
<input :value="getTotalTaxes(key)"
                       id="total_tax_breakup"
                       type="number" size="10"
                       name="total_tax_breakup"
                       class="table-control form-control">
```

Method:

```js
methods: {
  getTotalTaxes(index) {
    let calTaxTotal =
      parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[index].tax_SB) +
      parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[index].tax_SRP) +
      parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[index].tax_YQ) +
      parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[index].tax_RG);

    this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[index].total_tax_breakup = calTaxTotal;

    return calTaxTotal;
  }
}
```

Comment: @MelMacaluso Look at this

Answer (score 1):

I just did this `parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_SB)` and now i'm getting the sum of all tax_breakup, i think this shuold be right

Answer (score 0):

It seems you skipped going inside the array:

ie.

```
this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_SB
```

Anyway personally:

1. I'd change the tax breakdowns to be a v-for
2. Change accordingly ticketInvoiceItems in order for the above to work
3. This way you won't have to repeat yourself and you can sum up dynamically as many items as you want such as with

   const totalTax = [...singleTax].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

Comment: i try this: `this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_SB` in all my tax_breakup but in my `total_tax_breakup` it show my like "1010101010" if i enter "10" five time, like its concatinate all value and show me the result instead of show me the sum. @MelMacaluso

Comment: As you know + concatenates strings but if you sum a string which is a number it will interpret it as integer anyway and give you the sum. So that's not the issue... Any chance of spinning up a quick codepen so we have a look at some trimmed down version of the code?

Comment: Brother i dont know how to use codepen but i just did this: https://codepen.io/PartabSaifZakir/pen/OBaZXx @MelMacaluso

Comment: https://codepen.io/Venomzzz/pen/bmQKdZ?editors=1011

Slightly amended for convenience, make sure to identify that [pos] array as might be the cause...

I also stripped the Form class as there was no reference to that in your snippets.

Comment: i did just like that but their is a problem when i put values in `taxes_breakup` i get the total in `total_taxes_breakup`, but when i add fields dynamically, all the other field's `total_taxes_breakup` are same as the first field.. I updated the image in my Question you can see that. @MelMacaluso

Comment: one more thing in my `v-model` i use the index of `[pos]` like this: `<input v-model="form.ticketInvoiceItems[pos].tax_SB"` but in my `computed:{}`, i use the index of [0], like this: `parseInt(this.form.ticketInvoiceItems[0].tax_SB)`, am i getting this error because of this ... ? @MelMacaluso

Comment: That's what I was mentioning, I don't really know how that pos array key is generated and the relationship between that and the rest of the code unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182449/discussion-between-saif-zakir-and-mel-macaluso).